# New Job using Tridion for an Arabic Market

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager, language-cloud

I've currently landed a job after graduating with a degree in Arabic & History, however outside of computing being a personal hobby I have 0 experience in the field (though the employer will provide full training!)! Now, I've had a look at the basic tutorial threads and will attempt to acclimate myself to the intricacies of Tridion. Is there anyone who has worked with Arabic (or right to left languages) specifically?

Any other tips?

Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion community Umar! Let us know if you have a specific dev or user question in regards to Tridion (SDL Web), as this forum is reserved for specific tech Q&A. I would like to invite you to participate in a general user community discussion via the Tridion Professionals group on LinkedIn.

Comment: Like the others mention, your question is too broad for a decent answer here, but Emirate Airlines use SDL Tridion for their website, and they are a great showcase for right to left language capabilities, see http://www.emirates.com/sa/arabic/ for example

Comment: Hi Umar, we also have a [general SDL community](https://community.sdl.com) you might join for news, events, and feeds of content from all over the Web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umar, welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange and Tridion in general! Hopefully you'll continue to participate in the community here and elsewhere. Your question doesn't quite fit into the Stack Exchange model. If you check out https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask I think you'll find that your question falls under the "every answer is equally valid" point. As a general rule, questions should eventually end up with an accepted answer, which is difficult with questions such as this where any number of answers may be equally helpful. If you're interested in general tips and help I'd take a look at the many Tridion blogs available, or reach out to SDL directly to see if they are running any training sessions which will help you get a broad range of skills.

That said, I don't want to completely avoid helping you find information on your question, so check out this Q&A where Nuno has some good information on how to manage multilingual websites where language direction varies: [Modifying Templates for Hebrew and Arabic](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/modifying-templates-for-hebrew-and-arabic)

Comment: Wow, sorry for the vague question, but thanks for the informative answer! cheers!